# weight of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, cardinals

Let $\omega(X)=\min\{|\mathcal{B}|:\mathcal{B} \mbox{ is a base of the topology of } X\}$. In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology), it stated that if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $X$, there is a basis $\mathcal{B}_0\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ of $X$ of size $|\mathcal{B}_0|\leq \omega(X)$. How can $|\mathcal{B}_0|$ be less than $\omega(X)$? I thought $|\mathcal{B}_0|=\omega(X)$

I know that this is a silly question but I really do not understand. I appreciate all answers.

Comment: It really ought say that $|\mathscr{B}_0|=w(X)$. There’s a proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/268417/12042). As **5xum** says, it’s not wrong as is, but there’s no reason to use the inequality.

Comment: Well, if $|\mathcal B_0|= \omega (X)$, then $|\mathcal B_0|\leq \omega (X)$ is also true. But yes, you are right, it would be better if it said $$|\mathcal B_0|=\omega (X)$$

Comment: @AugSB: Not a duplicate at all: the questions are entirely different.